# Is it necessary the function is invertible to find the volume using this technique?

Tags: calculus

I have the following doubt when we calculate the volume of this solid:

[image]
[image]

Since we have to take the inverse of the function in order to find this volume, I've been asking myself if we can only use this integral when the function has an inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to use this particular method (sometimes called the "washer" or "disks and washers" method for obvious reasons) for rotation about the $y$-axis, the bounding curves need to be expressible as functions of $y$. (which yes, requires that both the functions be invertible)

However, there is a second method for finding a volume like this using cylindrical shells, and for that method we do not need the function to be invertible. The general method is covered here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-applications-definite-integrals/ab-shell-method/v/shell-method-for-rotating-around-vertical-line

In this case, that works out to:

$$
V = \int_0^8\left(\sqrt[3]{x} - \frac{x}{4}\right)2\pi x\, dx
$$

Which if you follow it through leads to the same $\frac{512\pi}{21}$

Comment: I'll note that usually, disks-and-washers is used for rotation about the $x$ axis and cylindrical shells is used for rotation about the $y$ axis. (But when the bounding curves can be written as functions of either $x$ or $y$, as is the case here, you can switch up which method you use with which rotational axis)